# Why is ajax-loader.gif attempted to be loaded instead of ajax-loader.png?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have installed jQuery mobile locally.

When I invoke the method : `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();` I receive an error message : 
css/images/ajax-loader.gif 404 (Not Found)

The file css/images/ajax-loader.png does exist. Should this method not be referring this file instead ?

A possible solution is for me to just add my one ajax loader with same name, but it should work out of box ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an answer to your question [Why does jQuery Mobile 1.1-rc1 use a .gif for the loading icon (again)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939745/why-does-jquery-mobile-1-1-rc1-use-a-gif-for-the-loading-icon-again).

Animated gifs simply are more supported then CSS animations, but you can switch to PNG if you like. jQM simply defaults to .gif

Comment: so jquery mobile defaults to gif for its ajax-loader within the code, but includes ajax-loader.png as part of its download pack. Strange...

Answer (score 6):

I solved it very simply, just download the file `ajax-loader.gif` ([here](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/images/ajax-loader.gif)) and put it on the local project folder where the error is signaling. In your case `css/images/ajax-loader.gif`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue, but changing the file permission for the "ajax-loader.gif" alone fixed the issue for me.

It was set to "No Access" for "everyone" #mac